# Dealing with Irregular Embedded ArrayFields in Django

Tags: python, arrays, django, postgresql, python-3.x

I am currently using Django with PostgreSQL. I use `django-extensions` to run custom scripts, inserting data to database. I have a model as below:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    """
    Bus routes of İzmir.
    """

    code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True,
        verbose_name="Code"
    )

    stops = models.ManyToManyField(
        Stop,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="routes",
        verbose_name="Stops"
    )

    terminals = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(
            null=False,
            blank=False,
            max_length=32,
        ),
        size=2,
        default=[],
        verbose_name="Terminals"
    )

    departure_times = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.TimeField(
                null=False,
                blank=False
            ),
            null=True, # This was added later to maybe solve the problem.
            default=[]
        ),
        default=[],
        size=6,
        verbose_name="Departure Times"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Route"
        verbose_name_plural = "Routes"
        ordering = ["code"]
```

As you can see, I have embedded another `ArrayField` to `departure_times`. My data has irregular shapes as mentioned in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField.size) as a *note*. So, naturally, it raises the error as below:

> **django.db.utils.DataError:** multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions

As mentioned in documentation as "the underlying field should be made nullable", I added `null = True` to my embedded `ArrayField`. However, I did not understand the following statement in the note in documentation:

> the values padded with None

#### The questions on my head are

1) Will I deal with those data, modifying the length of irregular lists as below?

```
[a, b, c, None, None]
[a, b, None, None, None]
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

2) Is there a built-in way to overcome `DataError`?

---

If you think seeing the script would help you to solve the problem, [here it is](http://hastebin.com/etesokacog.coffee).

---

## Environment

- python 3.5.1
- django 1.9.7
- psycopg2 2.6.2
- postgresql 9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there seems to be no participant to this question. Thus, I wanted to share my own solution. In short, I modified the script in a way of question (1) above, which means, I extended each list with filler `None` values to *equalize* the length of every list.

Assuming I have data as below:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
]
```

Desired output is:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3, None, None],
    [4, 5, None, None, None],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
]
```

So, I've just created a sample function in case anyone needs in future, as below:

```
def equalizer(data):
    largest_length = 0 # To define the largest length

    for l in data:
        if len(l) > largest_length:
            largest_length = len(l) # Will define the largest length in data.

    for i, l in enumerate(data):
        if len(l) < largest_length:
            remainder = largest_length - len(l) # Difference of length of particular list and largest length
            data[i].extend([None for i in range(remainder)]) # Add None through the largest length limit

    return data
```

Then there is not any `DataError` to show. This answer will be accepted as valid in two days if there are not any better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for sharing your solution it really helped me out. I believe however that I found a more elegant solution. He's my take on it:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         max_lenght = max(len(element) for element in self.NestedArrays)
         [[element.append(None) for _ in range(max_lenght - len(element))] for element in self.NestedArrays if len(element) != max_lenght]
         super(ParentClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Basically I'm overriding the default save method. Then modifying the NestedArrays attribute and finally saving it. This method would be added to the Model class that had this issue. In this case I called it ParentClass.

More info on overriding model methods [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

Hope this helps someone!